# Tomcat not working properly, its showing error

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat not getting started if I start using the command sh startup.sh
Tomcat not getting shutdown if I stop using the command sh shutdown.sh

```
sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib64/jvm/java/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/bin/setclasspath.sh
```

If I shutdown, I am getting the below error,

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib64/jvm/java/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/bin/setclasspath.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

If I run catalina.out, I am getting below error,

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.

# An error report file with more information is saved as:

# /tmp/jvm-20648/hs_error.log

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000095550000, 715849728, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

# 

# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.

# An error report file with more information is saved as:

# /tmp/jvm-28647/hs_error.log
```

Comment: What part of _"There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue"_ is unclear?

Comment: I can't get the Catalina. out logs details in the tomcat. The major issue is tomcat6 not starting properly.

Comment: Of course it's not starting properly, because _"There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue"_

Comment: I have already increased the memory size (setenv.sh), still showing the error. Kindly advise me, on how to increase the insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: You're only providing the error message, not your configuration - so we can't give you any other hints. Provide some steps to reproduce (check [mcve] for suggestions), not just the error message. There we might find something. So far you're claiming that you did everything right, but still have this problem. Also: JDK 1.7.0 and Tomcat 6.0.36 are _horribly_ out of date. And last, please let us know how much memory the underlying machine has at all.